# Error while saving Category in Magento 2.4.6-p1

Tags: magento2, database

When I try to save a category I am getting cloudflare timeout error and the category is not getting saved. When I checked the exception log I found this error `: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction,   query was: UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET attribute_set_id = ?, parent_id = ?, created_at = ?, updated_at = ?, path = ?, position = ?, level =   ?, children_count = ? WHERE (entity_id = '1337')`. When I restart the mysql service and refresh the same page the category gets saved. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To change time in **my.cnf**

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 7200
```

**Next thing you have to check Bellow:**
The reason behind this issue is that you are running a lot of custom scripts and killing the scripts before the database connection gets a chance to close.

If you can login to MySQL from CLI and run the following command

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

you will see the following output

[image]

You can see an above example
162 the command is sleep and time is 3850. This is preventing other operations.

These sleep command processes should be killed 1 by 1 using the command as follows.

```
KILL 162;
```

Once you have killed all the sleep connections, things should start working as normal again